# Loop over two datasets in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets, the first one is the dataset of borrowers, containing two columns which are the borrower ID and the amount he or she needs. The second dataset is the information of potential lenders, also with two columns lender ID and the amount they are willing to lend. I need to create a third column for the borrower dataset, which is the ID of lender(s) that has the smallest difference between the two amounts for each borrower, assuming the matching is one-on-one(A borrower cannot borrow from two lenders at the same time).

The Datasets I have

| Borrower | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 100 |

| Lender | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 95 |
| 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 3 |

The outcome I want

| Borrower | Amount | Matched Lender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | 100 | 4 |

I tried to write some double loops but they do not run well.

Comment: please provide a data example and the expected output as well

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance of the format here, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

**sample data**

I assume you work with `data.frames` so here some sample data

```
borrowers <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10,
  amount = rep((1:5)*300, 2)
)

lenders <- data.frame(
  ID = 11:15,
  amount = (6:2)*133
)
```

**solution using `data.table`**

I use `data.table` so we load the library first and then use `setDT` to make them a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(borrowers)
setDT(lenders)
```

We do a join on the nearest value using `roll = nearest`, but as you specify every lender can only be assigned once to a borrower, so for that we use `mult = first`. We then get the matches, so we join that back to the borrowers table, to also see the borrowers we cannot find a lender for.

```
borrowers[lenders,
  .(borrower_ID = x.ID, borrower_amount = x.amount, lender_ID = i.ID, lender_amount = i.amount),
  on = .(amount),
  roll = "nearest", 
  mult = "first"
][borrowers,
  .(borrower_ID, borrower_amount = amount, lender_ID, lender_amount), on = .(borrower_ID = ID)
]
```

**results**

```
#     borrower_ID borrower_amount lender_ID lender_amount
#  1:           1             300        15           266
#  2:           2             600        13           532
#  3:           3             900        11           798
#  4:           4            1200        NA            NA
#  5:           5            1500        NA            NA
#  6:           6             300        14           399
#  7:           7             600        12           665
#  8:           8             900        NA            NA
#  9:           9            1200        NA            NA
# 10:          10            1500        NA            NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I wonder in this setting if it would be possible to further customize the code of criterion a little bit instead of using roll = nearest.

Comment: Yes it is possible to use `roll = 100` for example but it works only one way, so you would need a `roll = -100` as well, so two joins, bind the rows together. Just specify your needs clearly in your question and I can see to change my answer accordingly. In this I assume for example the results must be max 100 below or above the borrower asks.